# nginx + php 7 + $_GET params + Homestead

Tags: nginx

My .htaccess is:

```
# nginx configuration 
location / { 
if (!-e $request_filename){ 
rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break; 
} 
}
```

I have nginx configured like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name prueba_nginx.net;
root "/home/vagrant/Code/prueba_nginx/public";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/prueba_nginx.net-error.log error;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

If I call: http://prueba_nginx.net/a/b/c

and I run the php commant: echo $_GET['url´] it **must return:  : a/b/c**
but **currently it is returning: empty.**

PHP:

```
echo "\n".'$_GET'."\n"; var_dump($_GET);
```

If I made the test with apache it works perfect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

what is the problem? Are there into the transformation from apache to nginx an error?

---

Thanks **Michael Hamptom** for your fast answer.
I checked $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and it is returning the right value: a/b/c
but I am wondering why is not working with $_Get.
I made the changes that you sugested:
.htaccess:

```
# nginx configuration 
#location / { 
#if (!-e $request_filename){ 
#rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break; 
#} 
#}
```

and I changed nginx file from:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
}
```

But when I restarted nginx I received this error message:

**[....] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!**

systemctl status nginx.service

```
status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-09-16 04:00:27 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 2645 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2559 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2696 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2562 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 16 04:00:26 homestead systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead nginx[2696]: nginx: [emerg] unknown "url" variable
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead nginx[2696]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

journalctl -xe

```
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead nginx[2696]: nginx: [emerg] unknown "url" variable
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead nginx[2696]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 16 04:00:27 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: It does tell you why it failed. `nginx: [emerg] unknown "url" variable` You made a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You've got at least two problems I can see.

First:

```
# nginx configuration 
location / { 
if (!-e $request_filename){ 
rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break; 
} 
}
```

This is redundant and conflicts with the earlier defined `location` in `nginx.conf`. It should be disabled or removed.

Second:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Unlike what you appear to have in `.htaccess`, `try_files` is the correct way to do this. But, you aren't providing the URL in the format that you want, and you only need to fix that.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
}
```

Of course, you should instead do what most people do, and *don't* do any special preprocessing in nginx. Instead, you get the request URI from the environment in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Which is of course best practice.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Comment: after following your suggestions: location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

to

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
} I restarted nginx I received this error message:

[....] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. failed!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

to reemplace:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

by:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;}
```

and made a:

**sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart**

Reference: https://www.codecourse.com/forum/topics/nginx-config-url-rewrite-on-laravel-homestead/4696